# Create contacts with google API

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to create contacts in my google account using the 2lo (2 legged oauth), to achieve this Ive created a service account using my test account AAAAAAA@gmail.com, this step creates a "new email address" for the service, something like: XXXXXXX@YYYYYYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

I'm able to access the google api with this account without the user intervention (2lo), and when I create a new contact using the api, this contact is related to XXXXXXX@YYYYYYYY.iam.gserviceaccount.com and not to the account I used to create the service account AAAAAAA@gmail.com, I can't see the created contact using my test account (AAAAAAA@gmail.com).

Is it possible to create a contact on my AAAAAAA@gmail.com account using a service account? what steps shou;d I follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create contact. You need service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved.

If you want to access user data for users in your Google Apps domain, then  [delegate domain-wide access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) to the service account. Then, your application prepares to make authorized API calls by using the service account's credentials to request an access token from the OAuth 2.0 auth server.

You may follow the [steps listed here:](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount) . It shows how to create a service account.